# Voxel clouds rendering in Unity

Tags: unity, rendering, raycasting, voxels

I would like to have realistic voxel clouds in Unity game - I found a very promising article on fast fluid simulations, however the the output of the algorithm itself is 3D grid of cloud densities (=3D texture). My question is - how can I render such 3D texture into clouds?

---

My research so far:
The original article suggest **two pass rendering** of particles for each voxel, in first pass reading output after *each particle*(!) is rendered. This approach is both [slow and outdated](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9492/43702) not leveraging modern shader pipeline in addition to being overly complicated. 
Searching for voxel clouds in Unity suggests using **ray marching** while the actual implementations does not seem to do any ray marching, but rather using [Fractal Brownian Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion) to same 2D noise texture. This approach gives decently looking results (with some problems addressed in [horizon zero dawn](https://www.guerrilla-games.com/read/the-real-time-volumetric-cloudscapes-of-horizon-zero-dawn) slides), but would not make use of my realistic simulation.
The most promising source I could find was this [answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9492/43702), namely last paragraphs. However the answer itself rather vague on actual algorithm and links it provides are either broken or inacessible.

Comment: From all information I managed to find actual ray marching is way to go, but sampling density along the ray(which is not a problem) is not sufficient to render the cloud - it does not take in account lighting, currently I am failing to derive the correct equating/algorithm for that.

Comment: I implemented  Raymarching in Unity Engine https://github.com/smkplus/UnityRayMarching